# Is there a position the menu elements of a wx MenuBar?

Tags: python, wxpython

Is it possible to control the position of elements in a `wx.MenuBar()`? I can't find it in the docs, but it seems like it should be an option. By default, menu elements, like `file`, `view`, `edit`, etc.. are at the left most position, and then each additional element extends to the right. I have a very simple gui, and thus only have one menu element called help. I'd like to position it `RIGHT`, instead of the default `LEFT`.

Answer (score 2):

Really you have methods to place menu to position that you want:

- Append(menu, title)

Add menu to the end of MenuBar (i.e. place it as most right element). title is a title of a new menu. If succed returns True, otherwise - False.

- Insert(pos, menu, title)

Insert menu in pos position (after that GetMenu(pos)==menu will be True). All menu in position after that will be shifted right. pos=0 is firts (left) position. if pos=GetMenuCount(), the result will be like by using Append(). title is a title of a new menu. If succed returns True, otherwise - False.

- Remove(pos)

Remove menu from position pos, all menu in position after that are shifted to the left. Returns deleted menu.

- Replace(pos, menu, title)

Replace menu in position pos and don't affect to other menus in MenuBar. Returns menu that was in that position.

Sorry for my English)

Answer (score 0):

The order of menu elements in a wx.MenuBar is based on the order in which they are appended to the menubar. In the code below, "Utils" will appear to the left of "File" (last 2 lines are the key).

```
menubar = wx.MenuBar()
file1 = wx.Menu()
file1.Append(81, 'Edit Accounts', '')
file1.AppendSeparator()
file1.Append(88, 'Set Link Duration for selected items', '')        
file1.AppendSeparator()
file1.Append(82, '&Quit', 'Goodbye!')

util1 = wx.Menu()
util1.Append(85, 'View Log File', 'View Log File')
util1.Append(86, 'Clear Old Log files', 'Clear old log files')
util1.Append(87, 'Open APPDATA folder', 'Open APPDATA folder')
util1.AppendSeparator()

util1.Append(83, 'Update Sizes for Selected Folders',
                'Update sizes for the selected folders in sqlite DB')
util1.Append(84, 'Zap sqlite DB',
                'Clean out sqlite DB (needs to be done occasionally)')

menubar.Append(util1, '&Utils')
menubar.Append(file1, '&File')
```

good luck,
Mike